# Has Iron Man ever had a suit without flight, and if so, how effective was it?

Tags: marvel, movie, comics, cartoon, iron-man

In the movies and cartoons (and presumably the comics), one of the major advantages Iron Man has is flight.  Most superheroes have it, actually.  Even the Mark 1 prototype (in the movie) has a limited ability of flight that Tony uses to escape.

Tony is able to get away with anything by being able to get away from anything.  Air superiority allows him to hold off the government from forcing to reveal his tech, and it's also a major contributing ability when he fights villains.

How effective would an Iron Man suit without flight be?  Are there any episodes, movies, or comics where Iron Man doesn't have flight capabilities?  Any where he loses them temporarily or permanently?

Comment: Even without his jets, he can still fly using his repulsors. Also he has roller-skates. No. Really. https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1uzo.jpg

Comment: I changed your title so that it actually reflects what you're asking in your last paragraph and does not come off as primarily opinion-based. If you feel like I've drifted off from your intention, don't hesitate to reword it. :)

Answer (score 5):

In the 616 (comics) universe, his first two armours (the MK I & MK II) had air-pressure boot jets.

The MK II was considered to have limited flight, but the MK I was considered to power extended jumps as opposed to flight.

All subsequent 'main' armours, had flight capabilities. There are many specialist armour to consider though and it's not always clear if these armours have flight capabilities or not.

At least one of the hydro armours had a built-in inner escape suit. This escape suit had limited capabilities, so probably not flight capable.

It's hard to say how effective the MK I was. On one hand Iron-Man won several battles, but on the other, there weren't many other people using flight capable exo-suits at the time. Flight was also one of the first upgrades the Iron-Man armour got.

Answer (score 5):

In the *Avengers Assemble* episode "Savages" (Season 1, episode 17) Tony Stark has "Stone armour" which he used to fight dinosaurs.  This armour didn't have rocket thrusting boots and was literally a martial arts suit.

[image: Stone Armor]

It came from Captain America challenging Tony to go without his tech for a full day.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This answer is a bit hard to read, but you don't really address the second part of the question.  (How effective was it?)  You should [edit] your answer to address that part of the question.  There are other tips for writing good answers at [answer].